# Is it possible to perform calculations with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB table for photo ratings and want to retrieve the highest rated photos.  I know I need to do this based on an average for the ratings sorted from highest to lowest.  The DB table looks like this:

```
id  rating  rated_photo_id 
--  ------  ------------- 
1   5       1       
2   6       1
3   3       2
4   4       1
5   7       2
```

Is it efficient or even possible to perform this calculation in the SQL query? If not would it make sense to maintain a second table that stores the averages for each photo_id?

Comment: It's possible, yes, and plenty efficient in most use cases.

Comment: In fact, often the db is the very best place to do this from a performance perspective.  RDBMSs are extremely efficient at doing calculations across large sets of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You DO NOT need a second table. The rating table has the information you need. Use [MySQL aggregate functions with `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT rated_photo_id, AVG(rating) AS AverageRating, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfRatings
FROM rating_table
GROUP BY rated_photo_id
ORDER BY AverageRating DESC
```

Output:

```
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
| rated_photo_id | AverageRating | NumberOfRatings |
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
|              1 |        5.0000 |               3 |
|              2 |        5.0000 |               2 |
+----------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: wow...I just tried it on 1200+ entries and it only took milliseconds.  I didn't realize it would be that fast!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with almost all databases. Check out the aggregate functions of MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Specifically http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's easy and efficient to calculate averages, assuming you've an index on the rated_photo_id column

```
 select rated_photo_id, AVG(rating) as average_rating 
       from photos group by rated_photo_id order by average_rating desc
```

For a specific photo could specify an id:

```
 select rated_photo_id, AVG(rating) 
     from photos where rated_photo_id = 2 group by rated_photo_id
```

Ideally your index would be (rated_photo_id, rating) to be covering for these queries--resulting in the fastest execution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just group by the photo id and get the average as the group is created.

```
SELECT rated_photo_id , AVG(rating) as rating
FROM photos 
GROUP BY rated_photo_id
ORDER BY rating DESC
```